# What is suffix annotation in rust?

Tags: rust

I read [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/primitives.html) docs and stumbled on this line.

`let an_integer   = 5i32; // Suffix annotation`

What is this mean? I am assuming that it have 5 as value and i32 as integer type. Is that correct?

Comment: yes `5` is value and `i32` is type.

Comment: @HarshadPansuriya What do you mean by "literal"? is that same as value?

Comment: @RobyCigar A literal is a fixed value spelled out in the source code, such as `10` (integer literal) or `"cat"`(string literal).

Comment: When you assign the value of the [literal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/literals.html) to a variable -- the use of a variable means you could use "Regular annotation" instead of "Suffix annotation" like this: `let an_integer: i32 = 5; // Regular annotation`. However, if don't define a variable -- like this: `println!("{}", 1 << 32)` -- and there are no "constraints" to [infer the type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/inference.html)  of the literal, then the "Suffix annotation" is best. Note you can use an underscore in your suffix like `5_i32`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's correct.  When you write the literal `5` in a program, it could be interpreted as a variety of types.  (A *literal* is a value, such as `5`, which is written directly into the source code instead of being computed.)  If we want to express that a literal is of a certain type, we can append ("suffix") the type to it to make it explicit, as in `5i32`.

This is only done with certain built-in types, such as integers and floating-point numbers, but it can come in handy in some cases.  For example, the following is not valid:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", 1 << 32);
}
```

That's because if you specify no type at all for an integer, it defaults to `i32`.  Since it's not valid to shift a 32-bit integer by 32 bits, Rust produces an error.

However, we can write this and it will work:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", 1u64 << 32);
}
```

That's because now the integer is a `u64` and it's in range.